# How to get a value from another sheet that should respect multiple conditions ?Then bring in next column a distinct value from the previous one

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm stuck at, a maybe, simple problem with a simple solution, but i've been trying for 2 days and maybe "i can't see the forest for the trees".

I have tried array Vlookup/index/match but the formulas are getting very long and hard to follow.

So, the request looks like this:

In Sheet "Detail" we have all the information(Teams/Task/ToolUsed/TypeofTask).[image]

In Sheet "Person" we have(Name/Team/CurrentTask):[image]

What i want for it to do is in the columns 2ndTask and 3rdTask - get a task from sheet "Detail" that will need to respect the following conditions:

- 2nd Task Search Logic
  search the TASK that meets
  **criteria1 = A_Tool1_Type3**( as A_Task3 is composed of Too1_Type3)
  if criteria1 Task = Current Task then bring next Team_Task that meets criteria1
  if not existing then go to
  **criteria2 = Tool1_Type3**
  if criteria2 task = Current Task then bring next Team_Task that meets the criteria2
  if not existing then go to
  **criteria3 = Type3**
  if criteria3 task = Current Task then bring next Team_Task that meets the criteria3
  would bring Team_task = A_Task4
- 3rd Task Search Logic
  search the TASK that meets
  **criteria1 = A_Tool1_Type3**( as A_Task3 is composed of Tool1_Type3)
  if criteria1 Task = Current Task or 2nd Task then bring next Team_Task that meets criteria1
  if not existing then go to
  **criteria2 = Tool1_Type3**
  if criteria2 task = Current Task or 2nd Task then bring next Team_Task that meets the criteria2
  if not existing then go to
  **criteria3 = Type3**
  if criteria3 task = Current Task then bring next Team_Task that meets the criteria3
  would bring B_Task11

I need some suggestions/hints on how should I resolve this.It can be also VBA suggestions/hints/tips/ticks ...

Your effort on any level is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Now, I must leave my office. I will try posting an answer when I will be home...

Comment: I am trying to understand what "The 2nd Task to be firstly searched in this combination TEAM+ToolUsed+TypeOfTask and if no value is found then go to next combination ToolUsed+TypeofTask and if no value found here also go to search by TypeOfTask" does mean. If finding the second task of, let us say, "A" Team which is different than existing first one, should the code continue searching until a different Tool and a different Type is found, too? Can you edit your question and show us the optimum for Person 1?

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the interest firstly :). I have added 2 result examples and the logic behind them. I have read it again and it made no sense :) hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Your last explanation made some more light, but you did not follow my advice, to show us what the code should return in case of the first person. I will  not start programming until I am sure that I correctly understood what is to be done, So, "Person1" having 'Task3-Tool1-Type3` pattern, the code must find something similar and (in this case) such a pattern does not existing for a similar task (of A). Then, it should search only 'Tool1' and return 'Task 1, 2 or 5'. 'Task1' being the first found. On a similar logic, will the third task be 'Task2' or 'Task4'? I understand, it should be 'Task2'

Comment: I meant, i could not understand that only the task must not be similar, or the tool, also, for the third one...

Comment: I have already added what it should return for person1 and person2.So Person1 has Team A_Task3 which has the following attributes TeamA_Tool1_Type3, so searching for a diferent task with this attributes(A_Tool1_Type3) results with no value, then we go to search a task in all teams with the attribute Tool1_Type3, if this does not give us a result we will search by the next attribute that is Type3 resulting the Task4 from Team A (result A_Task4).A_Task4 is different from Current task.

Comment: This is a sample file and maybe a little bit confusing, if you would like i can send you the main file that has the method i have used with some array formulas of vlookup that searches the second/third value with the help of 3 helper columns.And maybe will be much easier then.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear, on my taste... Since you firstly are looking for similar `Team-tool-type`, then for `tool-type`, why for the next criterion the searching rule is changed? 'tool' would be 'Tool1'. Why to be chosen 'Task4' not having the same 'Tool1' criterion? I asked to receive a rule. Should I understand that for first two criteria the code should search for similar `Team-Tool-Type', only the task to be different and for the unique criterion the good tool must be different? Different of 'Tool1' in the case of 'Person1'? It is not important to see the file without a clear rule.

Comment: I hope that 'A_Task3', 'A_Task4' from your last picture are only to make it more elocvent. Is it true? Otherwise, all what I have in mind must be changed, which is not so convenient...

Comment: A_Task3 is the current task , that is manually set , A_Task4 is the result from the search based on the criterias mentioned above.

Comment: Please, try focusing on what I am asking. Is it true that **if  `Team-Tool-Type' are similar, the Task will be chosen**? If yes, why to change the rule and choose something which is different? Now I will leave home and will be back in some hours. But, in the meantime, I would like you to clarify the issue in steps. Since Tool is 'x' and Type is 'y' the algorithm should do that... But something to be applied to all cases. If an exception exists, OK but define it.

Comment: I cannot create an algorithm on a logic I do not understand.

Comment: Person1 is in team A and has Task3 (A_Task3) now I would like to assign Person1 another Task(2nd Task) that has the same structure A_Tool1_Type3, if no task is found that matches this criteria it should look in all teams for the criteria Tool1_Type3(as he already has the knowledge for these) if no task is found with this criteria move to next criteria Type3 and here it finds A_Task4 witch is different from current task

Comment: I thought that all the occurrences will be searched in the same Team. Now I understand that the pattern is searched in all the range. OK to understand why 'task4' has been chosen as second task. But in order to determine the third task, the same 'Type' looks to be searched (in all the range). Now, in order to save time, when look for the pattern, I tried a piece of code firstly sorting the range according to A:A (TEAM). In such a case, the third task will be 'Task6' (B - Task6 - Tool3 - Type1). Would it be incorrect? Should I let the range unsorted, even if the criterion is the same?

Comment: Hey there again :), thank you for your time.As "Task6" uses B_Tool3_Type1 and the current Task3 uses A_Tool1_Type3 they are totally different.For 3rd task i've got  B_Task11 as it has B_Tool3_Type3 ( Type3 being the common ground for both tasks).The 3rdTask if now it complicates this job i would skip it as i have also a SecondaryTool column and could replicate the method from 2ndTask and add the criteria there.So no worry for 3rdTask.

Comment: I am afraid, it is something I do not understand. For Person2, since the first task is "Task1", how the third one can be the same "Task1"? I input the existing tasks in an array and eliminate them from selection possibility...

Comment: Its E_Task1 that means its team E_task1

Comment: It is a little difficult to process what you deliver. If `Task1` of team `A` is not the same with 'Task1' of team 'E', you should state it. When I firstly saw 'A_ ' I asked: "I hope that 'A_Task3', 'A_Task4' from your last picture are only to make it more elocvent. Is it true?" and you did not answer anything and of course, I deduced that my supposition is correct. Anyhow, now this aspect is clear. I would also like to understand the logic for the next issue: When looking for a pattern 'tool - type' and it cannot be found in the Team where the task belongs, how the pattern to be determined?

Comment: Should it be taken from the first team where this Task will be found?

Comment: I took your question like a challenge, even if it was/is not so clear (on my taste). Please, test he code I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It should be very fast, using array and all the processing being done in memory:

```
Sub testTasksAllocationAllRange()
 Dim shD As Worksheet, shP As Worksheet, lastRD As Long, lastRP As Long, arrP, arrD, arrT
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, arrTasks, patt2 As String, gT As String
 Dim p As Long, f As Long, kk As Long, El, strPatt As String, boolPatt1 As Boolean
 
 Set shD = Sheets("Detail"): lastRD = shD.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set shP = Sheets("Person"): lastRP = shP.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row

  arrD = shD.Range("A2:D" & lastRD).Value 'put the Detail range in an array
  arrP = shP.Range("A2:E" & lastRP).Value 'put the Person range in an array
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrP)    'iterate betwen the Person array elements
     For j = 1 To UBound(arrD) 'search for the pattern (Tool&Type) in the same Team
        If arrP(i, 2) = arrD(j, 1) And arrP(i, 3) = arrD(j, 2) Then
            'extract the pattern and the equivalent Type (patt2):
            strPatt = arrD(j, 3) & arrD(j, 4): patt2 = arrD(j, 4)
            Exit For
        End If
     Next j
    ReDim arrTasks(0 To UBound(arrD)): kk = 0
    arrTasks(kk) = arrP(i, 2) & "_" & arrP(i, 3): kk = kk + 1 'the existing task to be avoided
            
    If strPatt = "" Then           'if no pattern in the same Team, search for it in all teams
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrD)
            If arrP(i, 3) = arrD(j, 2) Then
                'extract the pattern and the equivalent Type (patt2):
                strPatt = arrD(j, 3) & arrD(j, 4): patt2 = arrD(j, 4)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
    'create an array only from elemnts containing the string "Task":
    arrT = Filter(arrTasks, "Task", True, vbTextCompare) 'keep only elements containing string "Task"
    
    gT = getTask(arrD, arrT, 1, strPatt) 'second task if pattern exists
    If gT = "" Then    'if not task according to pattern has been found
        'searching for Type of task:
        gT = getTask(arrD, arrT, 2, patt2)
        If gT = "" Then
            arrP(i, 4) = "No match"
        Else
            arrP(i, 4) = gT
            arrTasks(kk) = gT: kk = kk + 1
            arrT = Filter(arrTasks, "Task", True, vbTextCompare)
            'start searching for the third task (by pattern):
            gT = getTask(arrD, arrT, 1, strPatt)
                
            If gT = "" Then 'if nothing found serching by pattern
                'searching for type of task:
                gT = getTask(arrD, arrT, 2, patt2)
                If gT = "" Then
                    arrP(i, 5) = "No match": GoTo NextTask
                Else
                    arrP(i, 5) = gT: GoTo NextTask
                End If
            Else
                arrP(i, 5) = gT: GoTo NextTask
            End If
        End If
    Else
        arrP(i, 4) = gT
        arrTasks(kk) = gT: kk = kk + 1
        arrT = Filter(arrTasks, "Task", True, vbTextCompare)
        
        'start searching for the third task:
        gT = getTask(arrD, arrT, 1, strPatt)
                
        If gT = "" Then
            'searching for type of task:
            gT = getTask(arrD, arrT, 2, patt2) 'third task if pattern not exist
            If gT = "" Then
                arrP(i, 5) = "No match": GoTo NextTask
            Else
                arrP(i, 5) = gT: GoTo NextTask
            End If
        Else
            arrP(i, 5) = gT: GoTo NextTask
        End If
    End If
NextTask:
  Erase arrTasks: kk = 0: strPatt = "": gT = ""
  Next i
  'drop the processed array at once:
  shP.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrP), UBound(arrP, 2)).Value = arrP
  MsgBox "Ready...", vbInformation, "Job done"
End Sub

Function getTask(arrD2, ByVal arrT, sType As Long, Optional strPatt = "") As String
  Dim p As Long, El, boolFound As Boolean
  'sType: 1 - double pattern, 2 or else - Type of task
  For p = 1 To UBound(arrD2)
       If IsError(Application.Match(arrD2(p, 1) & "_" & arrD2(p, 2), arrT, 0)) Then
            If sType = 1 Then
                If arrD2(p, 3) & arrD2(p, 4) = strPatt Then
                    getTask = arrD2(p, 1) & "_" & arrD2(p, 2)
                    Exit Function 'double pattern has been found
                End If
            Else
                If arrD2(p, 4) = strPatt Then
                    getTask = arrD2(p, 1) & "_" & arrD2(p, 2)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
  Next p
End Function
```

Comment: @Matr1x: Glad I could help! Does it exactly what you need, or only something... I tried commenting the code in order to give you the possibility to adapt it, if (will) need some modifications...

Answer (score 1):

You can make this for two differents ways

1. Make a concatenate column with the values on two sheets and use this on simple vlookup looking by concatenate.
2. Use SUMPRODUCT formula the sintax is =SUMPRODUCT((SheetTasks!B2:B50=C2)*(SheetsTasks!A2:A50=B2)) the size of range for all conditions have be the same

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the info.I have tried the concatenate before creating the issue method and made 3 columns as there are 3 conditions to be met.But i need 2ndTask to be different from the Current one and the 3rdTask to be different from the other 2.

Comment: As Sumproduct formula i am not sure how that can help me ?

Comment: The SUMPRODUCT can be used too for SEARCH and REFERENCE fórmula, in this case if you use the result is the intersection value of conditions